# MySQL partitioning on tables with <10M rows

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I've been reading about MySQL partition tables on both MySQL docs and from other people's words. I kind of understand the benefits of it when tables get really large and access is mainly to a particular range over time.

I am working on a DB project atm, and have a table of less than 10M rows . I know it grows by time, but the growth rate is not huge. My question is, is it really necessary to partition tables with a only a few million rows? Didn't see anything about this in MySQL docs.

Comment: Probably no use for partitioning that table.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to whether your data(and index) is entirely loaded on the buffer pool.

If your data and indexes could not load entirely on the buffer pool, partitioning will effective to reduce buffer pool usage, and improve index scanning performance(InnoDB is needed to load index entirely when using an index).